# node.js mysql-simple-pool stops responding after 12 or so hours

Tags: mysql, node.js

At first I thought it had something to do with garbage collecting, but further looking into the problem, it seems like mysql is no longer responding to any of my queries.

Each of my models has a require('./db.js'); at the top of their files, which looks like:

```
var Pool = require('mysql-simple-pool');

var mysql_pool = new Pool(50, {
    host: process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1', //currently the db is on the server
    user: 'USERNAME',
    password: 'PASSWORD',
    database: 'DATABASE'
});

module.exports = mysql_pool;
```

Works great, I can do things like:

```
db.query('select * from user where username = ? and password = ?', [username, hashed_password], function(err, rows) {
    if (err) { 
        console.log("error in loginUser", err);
        return callback(err, null); 
    } else {
        if (rows[0]) {
            var user = new User(rows[0]);
            return callback(err, user);
        } else {
            return callback(err, null);
        }
    }
});
```

Except every 12 or so hours it stops answering.  When people try and login, it just sits there and I eventually get a timeout error.

If a user is already logged in, then everything that comes from memory is great, but the parts where I query the database doesn't ever respond.

Update:
I've found a little bit in the code, i'm just trying to think of what this should be.

```
connection.on('error', function(err) {
    // Check if the connection has been lost.
    if (err.fatal && err.code !== 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
        // Decrement the current number of _connections.
        pool._currentNumberOfConnections--;
    }
});
```

for some reason it's not doing anything when the protocol connection lost happens.  I'm wondering if there's a way to reestablish the connection once it's lost or what?  I'm assuming the problem is that the connection hiccups, and since i'm using a pool, they all basically get lost or stuck, and they just sit there.

Comment: Why not sharing a connection between all your modules? Is it feasible in your opinion that you're finishing all your connection?

Comment: Not sure I get what you're asking, this does share the same pool between all my modules, since it's exporting the same variable to all modules.

Comment: mysql-simple-pool is not active and lack of tests. I think you can make a stress test for it or switch to other modules.

Comment: hmm, do u know of another similar module that let's me treat a pool like it's a single connection?  Or maybe I can just look through the code and find a fix I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched away from mysql-simple-pool

db.php now looks like:

```
var easy_mysql = require('easy-mysql');

var options = {
    host: process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'USERNAME',
    password: 'PASSWORD',
    database: 'DATABASE',
    pool_size: 50
};

var pool = easy_mysql.connect_with_easy_pool(options);

//this is here so it fills in the place of mysql-simple-pool while i port stuff over
module.exports.query = function(sql, params, callback) {
    if ("function" == typeof params) {
        callback = params;
        params = [];
    }
    pool.get_all(sql, params, callback);
};

module.exports.get_all = pool.get_all; //these are here so i can slowly port stuff over
module.exports.get_one = pool.get_one; 
module.exports.execute = pool.execute;
```